# How do I make a object move in a gameboard actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

How do I make a object move in a gameboard using actionscript? I am using array and x&y axis. But its not working.

Comment: I'm doing a snake&lader game. so its a 10x10 gameboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what the array holds, and how you are setting positions. For objects which inherit from flash.display.DisplayObject, setting their x and y properties will suffice.

e.g.:

```
var num:MovieClip; //get it from somewhere -
....
num.x = 20;
num.y = 20;
addChild(num);
```

Comment: I designed the gameboard in adobe illustrator already. I already set the x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: var tiles:Array = [{x:165, y:507},{x:217, y:507} this is a sample of what I have but its not working

Comment: first, you haven't talked about the actual display objects you are adding to your board (sprite/movieclip/bitmap whatever).... unless we have this, we don't have any context.

Comment: Sorry I just started using actionscript. Umm, I think its movieclip?